# Ошибка, Netbeans 8.2 не видит jdk при подключении модулей

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java

При попытке активировать модули в Netbeans возникает ошибка:

> "Сбой при включении: Not all requested modules can be enabled:
>   [StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-spring-beans.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.form.kit jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-form-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.hibernate jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-hibernate.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.maven.kit jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-maven-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.kit jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.kit jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.java.kit jarFile:
>   /home/ruben/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-java-kit.jar]"

Answer (score 3):

В моем случаи решение было таково. Нужно было указать в файле netbeans.conf(*/home/netbeans-8.2/etc*) значение переменой `java_home`. Узнать значение переменной можно с помощью команды `echo $JAVA_HOME`.